# When does it changes orientation to default orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-orientation

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK.

My app only supports Landscape right orientation and it only has one view controller. I set the only available orientation modifying `myProject-info.plist`.

I'm trying to understand why this code outputs a log for a view in Portrait mode when I only supports landscape right orientation.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    UIView *videoView = self.videoPreviewView;
    NSLog(@"Video frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(videoView.frame));
}
```

Console output:

```
Video frame: {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
```

I'm working with `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and I need to set its frame, but when I do it on `viewWillAppear:` I get portrait values but `orientation` value is Landscape right.

**Is there an event or anything similar that i gets triggered when orientation changes to landscape?**

**When does the app changes orientation to default orientation?**

Answer (score 0):

Go into xCode, and click the project name at the top of the screen (with an xcode LOGO underneath it). 
Then reveal the iPhone/Ipad development info and select the orientations you want to be available for users :)

Comment: I said that landscape right is the only orientation available because I did that before. Sorry, this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Just to make sure, only landscape right is "highlighted" (black) right.
if that doesn't work then copy this code in each view controller :)
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation);
}

Answer (score 0):

If you add the line:

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

then it will call the `-(void)orientationChanged;` method every time the orientation is changed. You can then do something like:

```
-(void)orientationChanged {
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) {
        //device is portrait;
    }
    else {
        //device is landscape;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this to determine the layout of your views and setup based on the orientation.

EDIT:
You can also check if the orientation returned by the statusBar's orientation is equal to UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft/LandscapeRight/Portrait/PortraitUpsideDown.

Comment: I've added your code and `orientationChanged:` runs twice and UIDevice orientation is always Landscape right.

Comment: The orientationChanged gets called more often than just landscape/portrait. It aparently also checks a lot of inbetween orientations. What I do in my code is store a variable that has the current orientation, and if it is the same as the new orientation, I exit the method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `currentOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;` always return Landscape right orientation. The problem is `currentOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;` always is landscape but `UIView` has Portrait orientation on `viewWillAppear` and I don't know where it changes to landscape.

Comment: Oh, I don't know what could be wrong then. Whenever I set only Landscape Right to available in the target, it starts and is always landscape.

Comment: Yes, it starts with landscape mode but UIView has this frame:{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}, that it's the frame for portrait mode.

Comment: Where are you setting its frame and what are you setting it to?

Comment: I'm not setting is frame, and get its frame on `viewVillAppear`.